# Can C# preprocessor directives be nested?

Tags: c#, preprocessor

I have done some googling around but have not found any positive statements about preprocessor directive nesting. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
#if FOO
// do something
#if BAR
// do something when both FOO and BAR are defined
#endif 
#endif
```

I know I can do something like below instead but was just wondering.

```
#if FOO && (!BAR)
#elif FOO && BAR
#endif
```

(Edit) Actually I have a more complex nested statement already active in my code but it does not do what I expect. Hence my curiosity whether there is an official take on this.

Comment: I was wondering about the official stance on this, could not find any comments in c# language tutorials.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) does not say anything about nesting so I think the question is valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they can be nested.

```
#define A
#define B

void Main()
{
#if A
#if B
    Console.WriteLine("A and B");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("A and not B");
#endif
#else
#if B
    Console.WriteLine("B and not A");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("neither A nor B");
#endif
#endif
}
```

Outputs:

```
A and B
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUuTN9) for you to try.

You can comment out the two lines at the top individually to get different results, like:

```
#define A
// #define B
```

Outputs:

```
A and not B
```

---

Here's the same code with indentation that makes it clearer, though I would not indent the code like this. Overuse of conditional directives like this is a code smell in my opinion.

```
#define A
// #define B

void Main()
{
    #if A
        #if B
            Console.WriteLine("A and B");
        #else
            Console.WriteLine("A and not B");
        #endif
    #else
        #if B
            Console.WriteLine("B and not A");
        #else
            Console.WriteLine("neither A nor B");
        #endif
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use it to really exclude code from the executable for different software versions (sold for different prices). But it gets complex quite soon. I was just surprised I could not find any positive statement on it in C# language tutorials.

Comment: A different way to handle this would be to have distinct assemblies for the distinct versions, and only bundling the correct assemblies with each edition.

Comment: Or, make the code unavailable using licensing or flags.

Comment: Using flags the code would still be there in the executable. Wanted to prevent that.

Comment: Then distinct assemblies are a cleaner way. If you're heavily into dependency injection, then I would create one assembly with all the interfaces that the rest of the application can use, and then distinct assemblies with the implementations so that you drop in the right implementation for the right edition of your software.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on dependency injection. I have thought about it but as the project is very mature and complex it is not a viable option to refactor it at this point.